# Are Human Computer Interaction questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is under CS graduate majors in my host university, so I would want to confirm first here.

Please up vote if yes and down vote if no (where yes or no are related to belong or not belong).

Or please drop an answer if it is more suitable.

Comment: I think you could ask the question without asking on the meta, in the worst case it will get closed (closing is no big deal). HCI is considered part of CS so I think the questions are welcome.

Comment: The [Cognitive Sciences SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) also welcomes certain HCI questions.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see a problem with HCI questions in this forum. The more, the merrier.

Comment: IMHO, HCI may be a lot closer to Human Sciences than Computer Sciences, so related questions may be quite away from algorithms, formal-methods, complexity, graphs, logics etc. which are the core of CS. Moreover, there is a risk of questions which do not admit a clear definite answer.

Comment: @Romuald The question that the community seems to be wrestling with is this: should this site be about formal, theoretical, experimental, applied, pure, natural, physical, and/or social science? It seems like *everybody* here has a different idea of what should belong on this site... although the tendency seems to prefer formal/theoretical CS, which may not be the best thing for the site.

Comment: HCI is definitely part of CS, more and more.

Comment: @Patrick87, what you are claiming is not true. The site is not intended to be restricted to theory and there has been an agreement on that. Please check the discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/23/41). That is different from the issue of programming question. (I incorrectly posted this comment under another post.)

Comment: @Kaveh Where did I say that there was agreement that the site is supposed to be restricted to theory? If anything, I'm claiming there is little agreement at all. Ken Li, Raphael, Alex, Gilles, you, myself... we all have (if slightly, in some cases) different ideas about exactly what should be on-topic (of course, questioning the anti-programming stance has not been well-received, but even you felt that the networking question deserved to live).

Comment: @Patrick87, my comment was regrading to "although the tendency seems to prefer formal/theoretical CS". I haven't seen anyone defending that view at all. Computer networks questions are on-topic, we had before, and no one is saying they are not. (The issue is different from computer networks questions being in-scope or not, but should be discussed in its own meta post.) In any case, in scopes of each topic should be discussed separately (in line with the [general discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/23/41) about the scope which is computer science), no need to mix them up in a bundle.

Answer (score 6):

Our CS faculty even offers a bachelor course on HCI, so I'd say its definitively on-topic here.

Do watch out for questions that are not [good subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), are not vague, overly broad or otherwise unanswerable. These are the usual criteria for every question here (not just HCI questions), but in the case of HCI I think you have to be even more careful.

Answer (score 6):

HCI is one of computer science's many dendrils into non-mathematical topics. It's on-topic here. Note that Stack Exchange also has a [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) site, which I guess is to HCI what [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is to algorithms and semantics.